# What is the derivative of $\ln (x+3)$ with respect to $x$?

Tags: calculus

As $\ln(x+3)= \ln(x)+\ln3$, does it mean that the derivative is both $1/(x+3)$ and $1/x$ ?

edit: Thank you. Truely a brain fart moment for me.

Comment: $\ln(x+3)$ is **not** equal to $\ln x+\ln 3$; $\ln x+\ln 3=\ln 3x$.

Comment: There's a nice aesthetic to differentiating $\ln x + \ln 3$ and $\ln 3x$, and verifying that they indeed have the same derivative.

Comment: The fact that you have arrived at this absurd conclusion should tell you that your premise is mistaken, because I think you realize the derivative can't be both. Nothing wrong with making mistakes, you just have to realize what they tell you when they occur.

Answer (score 2):

No ln(x+3) is not ln(x) + ln(3) ln(3x) is ln(x)+ln(3)

Comment: Hence ln(x+3) from chain rule will be 1/(x+3) not 1/x

Answer (score 0):

ln(x+3) does not in fact = ln(x)+ln(3).Perhaps you are getting mixed up with the log law log(a)+log(b) = log(ab)?